# How do I find/target the most frequent word in .txt file and change it

Tags: javascript, word-frequency

I am trying to figure out how to find the one most frequent word in a text file and change that single word so that it wrapped in some thing else, for example: freewordchoice (free + frequent word + choice) and everywhere in the text where that word is the text the word could change. I have been looking like mad for something like this but I can't find it. I'm very new to Javascript which is what I want to use for this. To upload and display the text works fine, what I don't understand is how I target the most frequently used word and change it in the entire text before it actually displays on the browser. In my mind I need some kind of variable that find the word and somewhere to store the world and a variable where I put in what is to be added to or changed on the targeted word.

**Sample text:** The Project Gutenberg Etext of Aladdin and the Wonderful Lamp

**Info/question upt:** The code below finds the most frequent word in the full text of the sample text above. I now that the word is Aladdin. Problem is I can get it to replace the word Aladdin correctly. I does print out fooAladdinbar, like I want but instead of just changing Aladding = fooAladdinbar, it buts fooAladdinbar between every letter in the sample text.

THIS IS SOLVED, was a variable problem.

Comment: Do you have some test data? how will the textfile look like? What encoding? which languges special-charaters and so on?

Comment: I updated my answer to cover also the replacing part of your question.

Comment: this is where I have the demo I'm working on: http://internetstall.nu/demo/demo.html, I just upload a simply .txt file containing text. Not sure what you mean by languges special-charaters, I'm trying to get this done with javascript, but something tells me that isn't what you mean.

Comment: is the problem solved, already?

Comment: No but I updated the code just now because I ended up changing it a bit.

Comment: i updated my answer, this should solve your problem.

Comment: It doesn't even if I remove that comma (which I did) even before that, that section of the code already works and collects the word I want it to. It's in the regEx there is a problem. It does grab the word stored in variable bee and it does print it in the text. Problem is it doesn't print it instead of the word in "bee" that it's supposed to replace it puts it inbetween every word in the uploaded text. furthermore when I remove the last comma, for some reason the script doesn't pick up the last word then in this case "my"

Comment: I'm sorry, but your code is very complicated, may some else can help you, I cant understand the code.

Comment: I solved late last night myself :) thank you for the help though

Answer (score 0):

This is not perfect, but works, here is a demo:

*(This Demo just finds the frequent word)*

- it splits the text with an regex expression
- then counts the words
- then returns the most frequent word

```js
var data = document.getElementById("data").value;

var allWords = data.split(/\b/);
var wordCountList = {};

allWords.forEach(function(word){
  if(word !== " "){
    if(!wordCountList.hasOwnProperty(word)){
      wordCountList[word] = {word: word, count:0};
    }
    wordCountList[word].count++;
  }
})


var maxCountWord = {count:0};
for(var propName in wordCountList){
  var currentWord = wordCountList[propName];
  if(maxCountWord.count<currentWord.count){
    maxCountWord = currentWord;
  }
}
console.info(maxCountWord);
```

```css
textarea{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="data" >
<!-- start slipsum code -->

The path of the righteous man is beset on all sides by the iniquities of the selfish and the tyranny of evil men. Blessed is he who, in the name of charity and good will, shepherds the weak through the valley of darkness, for he is truly his brother's keeper and the finder of lost children. And I will strike down upon thee with great vengeance and furious anger those who would attempt to poison and destroy My brothers. And you will know My name is the Lord when I lay My vengeance upon thee.

<!-- end slipsum code -->  
</textarea>

<div id="result"></div>
```

**To Replace** the word you can also use regex:
*(This Demo just replaces a frequent word)*

```js
function freewordchoice (free, word, choice){
  var data = document.getElementById("data").innerHTML;   
  var replaceExpression = new RegExp("\\b"+word+"\\b","gi");
  console.info(replaceExpression);
  data =data.replace(replaceExpression, free + word + choice);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = data;   
   
 }


freewordchoice("<b>", "the", "</b>");
```

```html
<b>Before:</b>
<div id="data" >
<!-- start slipsum code -->

The path of the righteous man is beset on all sides by the iniquities of the selfish and the tyranny of evil men. Blessed is he who, in the name of charity and good will, shepherds the weak through the valley of darkness, for he is truly his brother's keeper and the finder of lost children. And I will strike down upon thee with great vengeance and furious anger those who would attempt to poison and destroy My brothers. And you will know My name is the Lord when I lay My vengeance upon thee.

<!-- end slipsum code -->  
</div>
<br/><br/>
<b>After:</b>
 <div id="result" >
   
   </div>
```

**Update:**

the problem is this line

```
common = 'the,a,do,in,with,this,so,that,of,and,not,did,when,what,were,went,was,as,  
if,who,had,at,can,you,which,while,will,to,till,then,them,their,she,  
he,once,out,no,must,many,me,is,it,his,him,her,about,have,i,has,your,  
would,where,whom,s,on,from,for,by,but,all,said,my,';
```

the problem is in the end of the string `,said,my,';` remove the last comma and it should work, like this:

```
common = 'the,a,do,in,with,this,so,that,of,and,not,did,when,what,were,went,was,as,  
if,who,had,at,can,you,which,while,will,to,till,then,them,their,she,  
he,once,out,no,must,many,me,is,it,his,him,her,about,have,i,has,your,  
would,where,whom,s,on,from,for,by,but,all,said,my';
```

Since through the last comma, the last word is a empty string.

Comment: When I try to run it I only get error, I see there are a string in the data part but how would I make it work with a .txt file uploaded to browser like I do here where I am working on this demo: http://internetstall.nu/demo/demo.html

Comment: this scripts file is not loaded, check the console of the browser (press F12).

Comment: @user3481279 did you see my last comment? the script file is not being loaded. Does my solution help? or do you need some more help?

Comment: pressing F12 didn't tell me much, not sure what I am looking for their either. only thing I have left is to figure out regExp, it does what I want half way. But instead of just changing the most frequent word to fooaladdinbar (if the most frequent word was aladdin then) it buts in fooaladdinbar between each letter of the string.